# Cache for asmx/js is not persisting

Tags: javascript, caching, proxy, asmx

How can I cache asmx/js call permanently? I tried with HTTPModule and implemented caching. But this cache value is expiring during next login. It is reset to one year back of the last modified date. Through code I am not doing that. Is there any default setting in  asmx for doing that? If so, is there a way to override the setting?

I used the below code to achieve this. Actually my requirement is to cache this call (GetMygrid.asmx/js) in browser cache for some days and to avoid 304 response. I am able to cache this call using HTTPModule.

```
private void EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;           

    var path = context.Request.Path.ToLower().Replace('\\', '/');

    if (path.EndsWith("/js") || path.EndsWith("/jsdebug") )
    {
        var lastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var expires = lastModified + TimeSpan.FromDays(5);

        context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(lastModified);
        context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(expires); 
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);

    }
}
```

This code works fine during runtime while I am accessing the specific page many times. (GetMygrid.asmx/js) I am not getting 304 response while accessing the page and getting the following cache header.

> Cache-Control: public
>
> Expires: Mon, 27 Feb 2012 04:52:11 GMT
>
> Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Feb 2012 04:52:11 GMT
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

**But my problem is when I login next time in app (closing browser and then logging in), this cache expires and value changes to one year back.** I  am using `GET` method for this call.

> Cache-Control: private
>
> Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
>
> Content-Encoding: gzip
>
> Expires: Mon, 21 Feb 2011 15:35:48 GMT
>
> Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Feb 2012 04:39:37 GMT

Don't have any code in the app to reset the cache one year back during login.

Not understanding why it is happening.

Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: If you add InlineScript="True" to your service reference on the page, the script will be included as an inline script. This reduces round trips. However, this means that they will not be included in your cache (if you get it successfully working. I haven't succeeded in that).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue as you, and I've come up with a theory ;)

From what I can tell, when the JS is 'first' requested (in a session although possibly application lifetime) the script module sets the 'Expire' header on the content piece.  What you perhaps don't notice is that your call to 'SetExpires' is silently ignored in this first case ... the internals of that method [un-documented I might add] only lets you set the expires header If and Only If the new expiry date is earlier than the one currently set... since 'now + 5 days' is not earlier than over a year ago it doesn't actually get set!

All other calls in (I think) are ok after this first one as whatever module provides these script proxies doesn't set the expires again on the 304s so your  call to SetExpires is considered 'Ok'.

What I don't understand is what causes this first '.asmx/js' call to be re-made when the browser should still have a cached copy with a future expiry local to it :(

Annoyingly the HttpCachePOlicy class is sealed so I've been unable to work around it :( (Putting your module first won't work as SetExpires will succeed for the script module uf called after yours)

I should add that this behaviour makes 'sense' as it means that the script proxies will *never* be out of date as they will always be re-requested... unfortunately for us the 304s are becoming quite costly and I  can live with it being out of date, so would like some control over this behaviour... ;)